# Are there any rules/guidelines regarding Spider-Man's appearance?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man

This question stems from the recent controversy over the new choice of Spider-Man for the Marvel Cinematic Universe. There are people who claimed it was unfair that they chose another white Spider-Man (Peter Parker), instead of the newer mixed-race Spider-Man (Miles Morales), while older fans or "purists" contend that Spider-Man should be portrayed as he originally was, as Peter Parker, and not the newer version.

**As such, are there any rules about what Spider-Man must look like that must be adhered to in films?**

Comment: Himarm: Feel free to hit me up in chat next week if you want to take another stab at this.  I think there's a question along these lines that'll work here.

Comment: @Keen id definitely be interested in reworking this question in the future.

Comment: How's this even remotely "unclear what asking"??? I can buy it being closed as "too subjective to be answerable", but "unclear"?

Comment: @DVK at least someone understood what i was trying to ask haha.

Comment: @DVK - Would you like me to reopen it so you can all vote to close it for a different reason?

Comment: @Richard - theoretically, yes. Practically, probably not worth the effort.

Comment: @DVK - My thoughts precisely.

Comment: @DVK the original version and the comments which someone nuked (thanks, richard) made the question overly ambiguous and undefined at the time. In its *current* state, it's no longer unclear.

Comment: @DVK I'd just like to point out that there is a definitive answer to this part of the question - "does a character like Spider-Man have a singular "ideal" look, and has there been any comments about this by, any authorities?" - as Marvel Studios recently gave Sony a list of must have traits and features of both Peter Parker and Spider-Man.

Comment: @DrRDizzle: I think even your latest version is still a bit unclear, because it mentions Miles Morales. For me, the unclear part was always whether the OP was asking a. “should Spider-Man always be Peter Parker”, or b. “Should Spider-Man/Peter Parker always look a particular way, for example be white”. (For example, in the new Fantastic Four movie, the Human Torch is still Johnny Storm, they’ve just cast a black guy as Johnny Storm.)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite That part of the question is simply background for why the question was asked. The main question ("What should Spider-Man look like?") is clear and answerable.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I've edited it further since. I fully believe that this question is answerable now.

Comment: @drrdizzle - On the strength of your comments, I've reopened this. I'm tempted to protect it though, as I can see it causing trouble.

Comment: @Richard Thank you. I feel confident in my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This article](http://birthmoviesdeath.com/2015/06/19/prudes-at-marvel-decree-spider-man-can-never-have-sex-with-minors) claims that when Sony Pictures attempted to reboot the Spider-Man franchise in 2011, Marvel gave them a list of rules about how both Spider-Man and Peter Parker should be depicted on screen. These rules are;

**Spider-Man**

- Male
- Does not torture
- Does not kill unless in defense of self or others
- Does not use foul language beyond PG-13
- Does not smoke tobacco
- Does not sell/distribute illegal drugs
- Does not abuse alcohol
- Does not have sex before the age of 16, does not have sex with anyone below the age of 16
- Not a homosexual (unless Marvel has portrayed that alter ego as a homosexual)

**Peter Parker**

- His full name is Peter Benjamin Parker
- He is Caucasion and heterosexual
- His parents become absent from his life during his childhood
- From the time his parents become absent he is raised by Aunt May and Uncle Ben in New York City
- He gains his powers while attending either middle school or college
- He gains his powers from being bitten by a spider
- He designs his first red and blue constume
- His black costume is a symbiote and is not designed by him
- He is raised in a middle class household in Queens, New York
- He attends or attended high school in Queens, New York, or he attends or attended college in Queens, New York

These list of rules show a number of things about what both Spider-Man and Peter Parker must look like, namely that Spider-Man does not have to be Peter Parker (but he does have to be male), and that Spider-Man can be any ethnicity (but Peter Parker must be white).

So in short - yes, Spider-Man does have certain rules about how he must be depicted in film, but these rules do not extended to the ethnicity of the character unless he is Peter Parker. According to these rules, Marvel Studios could have chosen to use Miles Morales as their version of Spider-Man if they had wanted to.

Comment: Just to clarify: I asume that *Sony* could not have chosen Miles Morales as their Spider-Man because they didn't get the rights to use him, but are you sure they could have made some other, original character Spider-Man, or did Marvel explicitly require that Spider-Man's alter-ego *be* Peter Parker?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield The fact that the rules define Spider-Man and Peter Parker seperately seems to imply that Sony Pictures could have made up a new alter ego for Spider-Man if they had wanted to, but he would have to be a male, and straight unless they were adapting a gay alter ego of Spider-Man from the comics. I'm not sure how the rights around Miles Morales as a character would work - he is classed as a Spider-Man property, but did not exist when the deal for Spider-Man was made. I assume that Marvel Studios can use Miles Morales, but not as a version of Spider-Man.

Comment: That's probably true, though I have to assume the terms of their contract likely got modified by the recent joint use agreement...

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Almost certainly. It'll be interesting to see both a) how long the Marvel Cinematic Universe goes on for and b) if we ever see Miles Morales thanks to that.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for and the original intent of my question, thanks for clarifying and answering.

Comment: "He gains his powers while attending either middle school or college" - What about high school?

Comment: @RogueJedi I'm just posting what the sources say... but aren't high school and middle school the same thing?

Comment: @DrRDizzle Not in America. Middle school is generally 6th to 8th grade. High school is generally 9th to 12th grade (It is called middle school because it is between elementary and high school). Peter is in high school in The Amazing Spiderman and graduates high school in the sequel.

Comment: @RogueJedi Probably just a typo or a mistake on behalf of the people who typed it up in that case. I won't be changing the answer, as I am quoting them, but thanks for pointing that out to me.

Comment: @RogueJedi To be fair, [someone raised the same question in the comments section of the article I referenced](http://birthmoviesdeath.com/2015/06/19/prudes-at-marvel-decree-spider-man-can-never-have-sex-with-minors#comment-2088372486). It wasn't answered.